# How does my JPA persistence provider know which side of my join table to apply my predicate to?

Tags: java, jpa, join

I'm using the JPA Criteria API. Given this TypedQuery:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Foo> cq = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> composite = cq.from(Foo.class);
SetJoin<Foo, Foo> relative = composite.join(Foo_.related);
Path<Long> relativeIdPath = relative.get(Foo_.id);
Predicate predicate = relativeIdPath.in(someIds);
cq.where(predicate);
TypedQuery<Foo> tq = JPA.em().createQuery(cq);
```

Does `relativeIdPath` know to point to the right hand side of the join table for the IN clause? How?

Comment: The how is provider specific, but does it matter?  You have asked for Foos that reference Foos that have IDs within a list.  Check that you get e correct SQL and results, and file a bug if you aren't.  Most will keep track of the tables and join them using aliases where you've specified joins.  A self reference shouldn't be much different than a join to a different table.

Comment: Does the JPA Criteria spec require `SetJoin<X,Y>.get()` to choose the right-hand side of the join? I'm worried that I'm depending on my provider's implementation, rather than the spec.

Comment: Yes, the returned path represents your joined relationship, not the originating foo.  Anything built from that path is built using the joined table/referenced entity, not the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting the `relativeIdPath` from `relative.get(Foo_.id)` which by the way is the join (`SetJoin`) itself.

Comment: The SetJoin itself has a left-hand side Foo and a right-hand side Foo. When I call relative.get(Foo_.id), does anything guarantee that the subsequent IN is checking the right-hand side Foo?